# Cleaning text Data For NLP tasks

Tags: machine-learning, text, nlp, chatbot, data-cleaning

This morning i've been trying to train a chatbot on the Cornell Movie--Dialogs Corpus Dataset  but i'm facing problems cleaning the text data to feed into my Algorithm.
Here is snippet from the text file

> 

```
L1045 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!
L1044 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ CAMERON +++$+++ They do to!
L985 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ I hope so.
L984 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ CAMERON +++$+++ She okay?
L925 +++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ Let's go.
```

L924 +++$+++ u2 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ CAMERON +++$+++ Wow
I am only interested in the dialogs at last part of each sentence.
How can i clean this file and make it a csv document?

Dataset Link
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~cristian/Cornell_Movie-Dialogs_Corpus.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over all the lines as a string.

Lets say you hav:

> str = "+++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!"

and you want out put as "They do not!"

Do like :

> str.split("+++$+++ ")[-1]

This will give you the desired output. Once you have the desires output as string write them line by line in your .csv file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this using simple regex.

**Code Snippet**

```
import re
string = "+++$+++ u0 +++$+++ m0 +++$+++ BIANCA +++$+++ They do not!"
cleaned = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", string))
print(cleaned)
```

**Output**: 
`'u m BIANCA They do not'`

To perform it on every line. I suggest you convert your data to pandas data frame and use .apply() method to get your cleaning done

Answer (score 0):

Try this library for basic cleaning : https://pypi.org/project/textcleaner/

There is a function named **remove_symbols()** you can also pass a list instead of a file as an argument.

Below is the documentation link to use this function. 
https://yugantm.github.io/textcleaner/documentation.html#remove_symbols

There are many other functions for the cleaning of text data.

I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the text into columns using '+++\$+++' as the separator

```
df=pd.read_csv('training_data/movie_lines.txt', sep = '\+\+\+\$\+\+\+', engine = 'python', header=None)
```

You will get something like below, then you can drop the columns that you don't want to use.

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   L1045   u0  m0  BIANCA  They do not!
1   L1044   u2  m0  CAMERON     They do to!
2   L985    u0  m0  BIANCA  I hope so.
3   L984    u2  m0  CAMERON     She okay?
4   L925    u0  m0  BIANCA  Let's go.
```

Now to drop the unnecessary columns use:

```
df.drop(df.columns[0:4], axis=1, inplace=True)

    4
0   They do not!
1   They do to!
2   I hope so.
3   She okay?
4   Let's go.
```

Answer (score -1):

The pattern is right there! `+++$+++`. Split it on that and you will get CSV data.